# ng-show ng-hide not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-show, ng-hide

I'm trying to hide a section when a variable is null.

```
<ion-item class="item-avatar calm" id="detalleDeCita-list-item29" ui-sref="volare2.perfilDelAsesor" ng-show="asesor" >
    <h2calm>Asesor {{asesor}} 
      <p>Ver perfil</p>
    </h2calm>
  </ion-item>
```

Controller

```
 $scope.asesor = $stateParams.asesor;
```

and it comes null. 
It shows the html segment no matter the value of $scope.asesor.

The same happens if use ng-hide or ng-if.

I've tried every combination possible but no matter what, it doesn't work.

Comment: try` ng-show="(asesor == null )" `

Comment: what you means is it alway hide no matter value of $scope.asesor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stateParams` params are always strings. "true" == true, but also "false" == true. You need to coerce the value to boolean somehow. Try this :

```
 $scope.asesor = !!$stateParams.asesor;
```

Comment: Thank you! that was it, it was getting null as a String!

Comment: @JoséHumbertoContreras you are welcome . please mark my answer if it helped